# How can I erase the "also please add" text in this website

Tags: html, magento-1.9

I'm trying to edit the home page of this website and until now I have been able to find most of the .phtml files but I haven't been able to find the file or menu that has this text at the end of the website (screen print https://snag.gy/jCcpgo.jpg ). Please help!

I already went to CMS/Pages/"home page". I found the Home.phtml file and the footer.phtml file and non of them have the text

Comment: can share the link to actual site insted of image, or html?

Comment: this is the page http://atoz.com.mt/

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing open all html file in any editor like vs code or sublime.

In sublime open all html file and do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and type that word you want to find so will get that file name so you can remove that word.

In vs code open that project and in left hand side open that search bar and type that word then you will get the file name that contain the particular words.

I have just seen your website the problem is very simple.

```
<div class="page">
```

which contain

```
<div class="header-container">
```

After the tag ends there are that word "also please add". just remove it and you are good to go

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check that